# How to manage git merge with essentially two masters?

Tags: linux, git, merge

we have the following situation:

- At time point t0, we took snapshot of C++ project in Unix, which was not finished (release 1702 under Unix), and worked on it migrating to Linux. This was established as Master in a new GIT server.
- At time point t1, I created a new branch from Master called 1702, and overwrote everything with the up to date Unix code.
- During t1, I made another branch linux_not_working, which is a clone of Master branch.

Now, I tried to merge 1702 into linux_not_working, with git mergetool for handling conflicts, and the result is bad: for example I modified all of the project's Makefiles to work in Linux, and the merge did not even display conflicts, just replaced them with the old Unix ones from 1702 branch, also I did not find how to tell vimdiff to take ALL from REMOTE and not LOCAL (as I understand it, BASE has no meaning in this particular merge).

- How best to perform this merge, when in a sense, I have two Masters going? I need to take any new additions from 1702, while KEEPING my customizations in linux_not working (manually, but its a lot of files so cherry pick is not ideal).
- Any suggestions for the future? They are going to have to do it at least once more, while a contractor is working on 1703 release, and only later production development will shift to Linux.

Essentially, what I want to do is for GIT to tell me for each file: "File R and L are different, which one you want to keep? (allowing me to take different parts of each, IF it happened to have been modified by both branches)"

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could describe in more detail what steps you took at t1? I think this could be a lot of things, so more details would help.

Comment: @oyvind during t1, I created the new branch based on Master via the Git GUI (central cloud platform, Atlassian I think). Then on terminal, I did git pull, git checkout linux_not_working, followed by git merge 1702, then started on git mergetool. Does that help?

Comment: It's hard to tell why it won't let you properly resolve conflicts. Were files moved and/or renamed in the changes of 1702?

Answer (score 0):

> Essentially, what I want to do is for GIT to tell me for each file: "File R and L are different, which one you want to keep? (allowing me to take different parts of each, IF it happened to have been modified by both branches)"

If you don't need 3-way merge, you can simply check out the content of the branch and review the change with `git gui`.

```shell
$ git checkout -b manual-merge linux_not_working
$ git checkout 1702 . # overwrites source with 1702's one
$ git gui             # take or leave each diff
$ git commi
```

(Or you may want to do it backwards.)

```shell
$ git checkout -b manual-merge-2 1702
$ git checkout linux_not_working .
$ git gui
$ git commit
```

Once you have manually-merged result, you can overwrite and commit as a merge.

```shell
$ git checkout 1702
$ git merge linux_not_working
$ git reset
$ git checkout manual-merge . # or manual-merge-2
$ git commit
```

Comment: The last set of commands refers to which case?  first or the backward one?

Comment: You can apply in either case. I updated the example to clarify and use throw-away branches.